# Onclick requires two clicks for element, when clicking friend element, it requires 2 clicks for it to become true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click friend button, it takes 2 clicks to become true I want to click just once and for isFriend to be set true

```
function FriendChoice({friend, index}) {
    const [showHobbies, setShowHobbies] = useState(false);
    const [friendClicked, setFriendClicked] = useState(false);
    // const[isFriend, setIsFriend] = useState(false);
    // const[showActivity, setShowActivity] = useState(false);
    const db = getDatabase();
    let friendClass = "friend-card";
    const handleClick = async () => {
        try {
            const path = "Friends/" + index + "/isFriend";
            const friendRef = ref(db, path);
            setFriendClicked(!friendClicked);
            await firebaseSet(friendRef, friendClicked);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

   if(friend.isFriend) {
   friendClass = "friend-card friend-card-clicked";
 }

return (
<div className={friendClass} onClick={handleClick} onMouseEnter={() => setShowHobbies(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setShowHobbies(false)}>
  <img src={friend.img} alt={friend.alt} />
  <div className="d-flex flex-column friend-font">
    {!showHobbies && (
      <p><strong>{friend.name}</strong></p>
    )}
    {showHobbies && (
      <p>
        A:{friend.activity} H:{friend.hobby}
      </p>
    )}
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

Thank you for your help javascript class have around 2 hours to submit

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's hard to tell what's inside which functions.

Comment: What templating framework is this? Add that tag to the question.

Comment: Setters in React's useState are asynchronous, and do not immediately assign the passed in value to its variable. The first time you click, it runs the setter but it does not actually finish executing the function right away. By the time you click a second time, the setter has executed and it looks like it only works on your second click

Comment: @Barmar I believe this is Reactjs, I added it in a suggested edit

Comment: What is `setFriendClicked(!friendClicked);` doing, and why is it immediately _before_ `await firebaseSet(friendRef, friendClicked);`? Does it explain why it takes two clicks?

Comment: @traktor It's updating the state variable. Using `!friendClicked` toggles the value.